# Chrome/Safari not Caching CSV files. Firefox works

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, webkit, cache-control

I am using a simple Express Server to serve static files. I have different file types under the served folder `pdf,csv,txt,zip`.
I have the following code

```
app.use('/d', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'd'), {
  index: 'false',
  fallthrough: false,
  redirect: false,
  setHeaders: (res, path) => {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=2592000000');
    res.setHeader("Expires", new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000).toUTCString());
  }
}));
```

Chrome/Safari is caching all files except `csv,zip`.
Firefox caches all files including `csv,zip`

Does Chrome/Safari does not cache CSVs and Zip files??

I tried playing around with Expires and Cache-control both. Made sure that e-tag is set properly. But still no luck. Any thoughts?